Kernel dying with large dataset aggregations on polars
I am trying to run queries involving aggregations by using polars on large datasets. I used streaming=True, and yet, the kernel keeps dying. What could be the problem? How do I fix it?
def base_medium_polars_queries(log_dir, result_file):
  print(",base_medium_polars_queries")
  df = pl.scan_csv(log_dir)  # Lazy loading of CSV
  query_index = 0
  for ix, iy in combinations:
      for col in ['request_io_size_bytes', 'disk_time']:
          query_index += 1
          t1 = time.time()
        
          # Perform first group_by aggregation on two columns
          res = df.group_by([ix, iy]).agg(pl.col(col).sum())
        
          # Perform secondary aggregation on the result of the first aggregation
          res = res.group_by(ix).agg(pl.col(col).sum()).collect(streaming=True)
        
          # Measure time and memory usage
          time_elapsed = time.time() - t1
          memory_usage = res.estimated_size()

          # Log results
          log_results_to_file(result_file, time_elapsed, memory_usage)
        print(f"medium,Q{query_index},{time_elapsed},{memory_usage}")
base_medium_polars_queries("../datasets_thesios_io_traces/dataset-125m.csv", "results_rust_medium_queries_csv/results_rust_base_medium_125m.txt")


Do you have enough RAM to hold res? Does the same thing happen if you convert the csv to parquet (sink_parquet) and use df = pl.scan_parquet instead of CSVs?

I am going to try that. However, isn't sink_parquet going to kill the whole purpose of trying to find memory_usage in the df? sink_parquet will send the output to a parquet file since it cannot fit in memory. Thus, should I even be looking for memory_usage at this point? Btw, I didn't mention it but it seems implied by my code - I am running benchmarks.

I guess I was trying to ask if you could test the whole benchmark to see if it happens with parquet data. The mention of sink_parquet was just to show that you can use Polars to first convert the dataset to parquet (not to use it in your benchmark). The idea being it may help to know if is a general issue - or specific to the csv reader.

Parquet dataset is more compact, however, when working with a huge dataset (27GB) with many unique values, it is almost inevitable to run into this issue. The solution that I found was to increase the swap memory and apply spilling into a directory. However, I found out that the amount of execution time that it takes, makes applying complex queries (like explode) on such large datasets infeasible.
